# Which SQL datatype can be used to store mobile numbers in numeric forms, without including characters like brackets and hyphens?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-modeling

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper
(
    Shopperid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    Gender VARCHAR2(6) CHECK(Gender IN ('Male', 'Female')),
    MobileNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

I'm trying to create a table and I want my mobile no. to be devoid of any hyphens and brackets.

Comment: A number won't work, what if you have a leading zero?  (intl numbers)

Comment: Try using `VARCHAR2(10)` or `CHAR(10)`

Comment: not null?  that is gunna be trouble.

Comment: `CHECK(Gender IN ('Male', 'Female'))` - not very welcoming or inclusive. Also, what sort of shopping application even needs to know the gender of its customers? Given that this task seems to be taken from a training app the assumptions underlying the data model are worrying.

Answer (score 4):

Store the value as a string with a check constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper (
    Shopperid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    Gender VARCHAR2(6) CHECK (Gender IN ('Male', 'Female')),
    MobileNo VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(MobileNo, '^[0-9]*$')),
    Address VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

Comment: Why the size is 30 tho?

Comment: @samg - 10 probably isn't enough; subscriber numbers are up to 12 digits for E.164, and could have a leading zero on top of that. In some scenarios - though not here - you might allow for full E.164, or extensions, etc. So here 30 might be excessive but it doesn't really hurt. If the OP can constrain to a particular length then fine, of course.

Comment: @AlexPoole: according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbering_plan#International_numbering_plan)  the maximum length is 15

Comment: I referred to the subscriber number, [which is max 12](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164), just as the shortest element potentially making 10 insufficient. Full E.164 would need more, but we don't know what's needed.It's possible a smaller limit would still be OK if entries are restricted to numbers for certain countries, which I hadn't considered. But still 10 might not be enough; 15 should be; or 16 if the + is wanted (which Gordon's check disallows - but just noticed that only allows a single digit *8-). <shrug>

Answer (score -2):

**This is the code posted in the question by Jazir Ahammed**

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper
(
    Shopperid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    Gender VARCHAR2(6) CHECK(Gender IN ('Male', 'Female')),
    MobileNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

**This is the post by Gordon Linoff**

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper (
    Shopperid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
    Gender VARCHAR2(6) CHECK (Gender IN ('Male', 'Female')),
    MobileNo VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(MobileNo, '^[0-9]$')),
    Address VARCHAR2(50)
);
```

**This is the answer for INFYTQ's collaboration assignment 2 on DBMS**

```
CREATE TABLE Shopper(
Shopperid INTEGER,
ShopperName VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
Gender CHAR(6),
MobileNo NUMBER NOT NULL,
Address VARCHAR2(50),
CONSTRAINT  s_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(ShopperId),
CONSTRAINT s_gender_ck CHECK(Gender IN ('Male', 'Female'))
)
```

[image of output at InfyTQ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tl1y.png)

Comment: how exactly does this answer the question??? this "answer" is basically a copy of the question without formatting and a rearrangement of some of the constraint clauses!!!

Comment: Please have a careful look at the 3 codes: 1) the one that was posted as question, 2) the one that was answered previously before my post 3) and the one that was answered by me. If you still find difficulty in spotting out the difference among them, kindly let me know so that I can help you with it.-@GMc

Comment: Posting some code from another site - even if you acknowledge provenance - does not constitute a decent answer. If you think your answer is better than Gordon's proposal and actually solves the problem the OP has you should explain why.

Comment: Sure, it's my pleasure to explain. And THANKS to everyone whoever marked my answer as un-useful that was motivating. Now let me explain, My code worked fine with InfyTQ, when I replaced VARCHAR2 with CHAR as that was the constraint set by them for GENDER. Another difference to be noted is, I have set Table level constraints to the Table, while @GMc has preferred column level constraints. And for a SQL datatype that can be used to store mobile number in numeric forms, without including characters like brackets and hyphens- NUMBER datatype will be the apt one when compared to VARCHAR2. -@APC

Comment: And let me remind that this piece of code I posted was not some code from any other site. And I believe this is a decent answer as I have spent time on checking why my code wouldn't work until I came up with this piece of code as conclusion. And finally to my surprise it actually worked. Screenshot has been attached for reference. -@APC

Comment: FWIW, i did not down vote you (yet). but the problem, IMHO, was that you provided an answer without formatting (hard to read) that looked very similar to the original question - especially for the field the OP asked about with no explanation. Then after some feedback this answer had three sets of DDL, still with no explanation. You know what you meant, but others can not read your mind. FWIW, I have no preference where the collumn checks are placed, i was merely pointing out that i had read your unformatted answer and noted that difference.

Comment: @Bhanu_Mathi Please do not take any of this as a personal atttack, the feedback is intended to provide you with insight as to how others have been confused by your post(s). It would be helpful if you put some text explaining how the three blocks of code relate into the body of the answer (rather than leaving it in comments for people to find). But I will leave it up to you to decide whether or not you wish to do that.

Comment: Yes @GMc I can understand what you have told. Thank You, I will give clear answers from now on. I have learnt this from you, as I am new to answering in stackoverflow.

Comment: If you had only posted your solution, you probably wouldn't have gotten the downvotes. Repeating the question's code and other answers is useless at best in a different answer. Regarding the constraints: there is no real difference between a column level and table level check constraints. At the end all check constraints are table level constraints. Putting them in a different position is merely syntactic sugar. And the use of `CHAR` is strongly discouraged. It has absolutely no advantage whatsoever, but a lot of nasty disadvantages.